# force grep to show only unmatched part of a word in bash

Tags: linux, bash

After several grep's I am able to have a list of some "words" like this

everything starts as

```
cat \path\verilargestructured.txt | grep option1 -B50 | grep option2 -A30 | grep option3 -A20 | grep "=host"
```

which result in a list with this structure

```
part1.part2.part3.part4=host
part1.part2.part3.part4=host
...
part1.part2.part3.part4=host
```

I want to use sed or any other option in bash to trim that out to

```
part1.part2.part3.part4
```

or

```
part2.part3.part4
```

assuming `partN` is only alphanumeric (no special characters)

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic? When does it show parts 1-4, when does it only show parts 2-4?

Comment: always is show part1.part2.part.3.part4=host and I need only part1.part.2.part3.part4 for one purpose and part2.part3.part4 for another one

Comment: Then why did you say `or part2.part3.part4`?

Comment: You just want to remove `=host` from the end of the lines?

Comment: practically I need to remove the =host at the end for one purpose and everithig is before first point from that for the next purpose

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then pipe it through

```
sed 's/=.*//'
```

...that will cut off the first `=` in each line and everything that comes after it. So, all in all,

```
cat \path\verilargestructured.txt | grep option1 -B50 | grep option2 -A30 | grep option3 -A20 | grep "=host" | sed 's/=.*//'
```

Alternatively, you could use `cut`:

```
cut -d = -f 1
```

Addendum: Going the `cut` route, to isolate all but `part1`, you could pipe it through yet another `cut` call

```
cut -d . -f 2-
```

As in

```
echo 'part1.part2.part3.part4=host' | cut -d = -f 1 | cut -d . -f 2-
```

Here `-f 2-` means "from the second field to the last." if you only wanted parts 2 and 3, you could use `-f 2-3`, and so forth. See `man cut` for details.

Comment: `$ echo 'part1.part2.part3.part4=host' | sed 's/^[^.]*\.\|=.*//g'`

Comment: I like `echo 'part1.part2.part3.part4=host' | cut -d = -f 1 | cut -d . -f 2-` better for that.

Answer (score 1):

With awk, you can specify multiple delimiters with the -F parameter and output field separator with OFS option.
For example `awk -F '[.=]' '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=.` will print only second, third and fourth row of your output separated with dot.

```
cat \path\verilargestructured.txt | grep option1 -B50 | grep option2 -A30 | grep option3 -A20 | grep "=host" | awk -F '[.=]' '{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS=.
```